I got an error in rust using wgpu and winit. To be more precise my error comes up in the eventloop part
I want to make my own game engine and for that I want that the user later on can use these traits I created to define the game logic and rendering to the screen. Also it should be fairly easy to create the window.
The error comes up in the event loop where I try to call my functions I created earlier but somehow I cant use a function that needs &mut self. I already tried using Rc and RefCell aswell as channels which both did not help me with my problem.
        event_loop
            .run(move |event, control_flow| {
                let mut app = app.lock().unwrap();

                match event {
                    Event::Resumed => {
                        log::debug!("Resumed");
                    }
                    Event::WindowEvent {
                        ref event,
                        window_id,
                    } if window_id == self.window.id() => match event {
                        WindowEvent::CloseRequested => control_flow.exit(),
                        WindowEvent::Resized(physical_size) => {
                            log::info!("physical_size: {physical_size:?}");
                            surface_configured = false;
                            // self.resize(*physical_size);
                            let mut app_ref = app.deref_mut();
                            app_ref.resize(*physical_size);
                        }

                        WindowEvent::RedrawRequested => {
                            self.window.request_redraw();

                            app.system.update();
                        }

                        _ => {}
                    },
                    _ => {}
                }
            })
            .unwrap();

And here is the the full compiler diagnostic:
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `**app_ref` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
   --> src\core\engine.rs:141:21
    |
141 |                     app_ref.resize(*physical_size); 
    |                     ^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

How can I fix my code?
Here is the full code:
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use std::iter;
use std::ops::DerefMut;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};
use wgpu::{Device, Queue, Surface, SurfaceConfiguration};
use winit::{
    dpi::PhysicalSize,
    event::*,
    event_loop::{self, EventLoop},
    keyboard::{KeyCode, PhysicalKey},
    window::{Window, WindowBuilder},
};
pub trait GameSystem {
    fn render(&self);
    fn update(&self);
    fn handle_input(&mut self);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Engine<'a, T: GameSystem> {
    system: T,
    surface: Surface<'a>,
    device: Device,
    queue: Queue,
    config: SurfaceConfiguration,
    size: PhysicalSize<u32>,
    window: &'a Window,
}

impl<'a, T: GameSystem> Engine<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(system: T, window: &'a Window) -> Self {
        env_logger::init();

        let mut surface_configured = false;

        let size = window.inner_size();

        let instance = wgpu::Instance::new(wgpu::InstanceDescriptor {
            backends: wgpu::Backends::PRIMARY,
            ..Default::default()
        });

        let surface = instance
            .create_surface(window)
            .expect("ENGINE_ERROR: Failed to create WGPU Surface");

        let (adapter, device, queue) = pollster::block_on(async {
            let adapter = instance
                .request_adapter(&wgpu::RequestAdapterOptions {
                    power_preference: wgpu::PowerPreference::default(),
                    compatible_surface: Some(&surface),
                    force_fallback_adapter: false,
                })
                .await
                .expect("ENGINE_ERROR: Failed to Request Adapter");

            let (device, queue) = adapter
                .request_device(
                    &wgpu::DeviceDescriptor {
                        label: None,
                        required_features: wgpu::Features::empty(),
                        required_limits: wgpu::Limits::default(),
                    },
                    None,
                )
                .await
                .expect("ENGINE_ERROR: Failed to request Device");

            (adapter, device, queue)
        });

        let surface_caps = surface.get_capabilities(&adapter);

        let surface_format = surface_caps
            .formats
            .iter()
            .copied()
            .find(|f| f.is_srgb())
            .expect("ENGINE_ERROR: Couln't find surface_format");

        let config = wgpu::SurfaceConfiguration {
            usage: wgpu::TextureUsages::RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
            format: surface_format,
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height,
            present_mode: surface_caps.present_modes[0],
            alpha_mode: surface_caps.alpha_modes[0],
            desired_maximum_frame_latency: 2,
            view_formats: vec![],
        };

        Engine {
            system: system,
            surface: surface,
            device: device,
            queue: queue,
            config: config,
            size: size,
            window: window,
        }
    }

    fn render(&mut self) {
        let output = self
            .surface
            .get_current_texture()
            .expect("ENGINE_ERROR: Failed getting current surface texture");
        let view = output
            .texture
            .create_view(&wgpu::TextureViewDescriptor::default());

        let mut encoder = self
            .device
            .create_command_encoder(&wgpu::CommandEncoderDescriptor {
                label: Some("Render Encoder"),
            });

        {
            let _render_pass = encoder.begin_render_pass(&wgpu::RenderPassDescriptor {
                label: Some("Render Pass"),
                color_attachments: &[Some(wgpu::RenderPassColorAttachment {
                    view: &view,
                    resolve_target: None,
                    ops: wgpu::Operations {
                        load: wgpu::LoadOp::Clear(wgpu::Color {
                            r: 0.1,
                            g: 0.2,
                            b: 0.3,
                            a: 1.0,
                        }),
                        store: wgpu::StoreOp::Store,
                    },
                })],
                depth_stencil_attachment: None,
                occlusion_query_set: None,
                timestamp_writes: None,
            });
        }

        self.queue.submit(iter::once(encoder.finish()));
        output.present();
    }

    fn resize(&mut self, new_size: winit::dpi::PhysicalSize<u32>) {
        if new_size.width > 0 && new_size.height > 0 {
            self.size = new_size;
            self.config.width = new_size.width;
            self.config.height = new_size.height;
            self.surface.configure(&self.device, &self.config)
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&self, event_loop: EventLoop<()>) {
        // let mut surface_configured_thread = Arc::clone(&Arc::new(Mutex::new(false)));

        let mut surface_configured = false;
        let app = Arc::new(Mutex::new(self));

        event_loop
            .run(move |event, control_flow| {
                let mut app = app.lock().unwrap();

                match event {
                    Event::Resumed => {
                        log::debug!("Resumed");
                    }
                    Event::WindowEvent {
                        ref event,
                        window_id,
                    } if window_id == self.window.id() => match event {
                        WindowEvent::CloseRequested => control_flow.exit(),
                        WindowEvent::Resized(physical_size) => {
                            log::info!("physical_size: {physical_size:?}");
                            surface_configured = false;
                            // self.resize(*physical_size);
                            let mut app_ref = app.deref_mut();
                            app_ref.resize(*physical_size);
                        }

                        WindowEvent::RedrawRequested => {
                            self.window.request_redraw();

                            app.system.update();
                        }

                        _ => {}
                    },
                    _ => {}
                }
            })
            .unwrap();
        // self.system.handle_input();
        // self.system.update();
        // self.system.render();
    }
}


The type of app is Arc<Mutex<&Engine>> meaning you'll only get immutable access to the engine since you're only protecting a shared reference. Your run only has &self. If you change it to &mut self (and avoid using self in your loop, use app instead), then it will work.
However, in this case since event_loop.run loops in-place, it doesn't require a 'static lifetime and therefore you don't need to use Arc or Mutex in the first place. Just use self everywhere:
pub fn run(&mut self, event_loop: EventLoop<()>) {
    let mut surface_configured = false;

    event_loop
        .run(move |event, control_flow| match event {
            Event::Resumed => {
                log::debug!("Resumed");
            }
            Event::WindowEvent {
                ref event,
                window_id,
            } if window_id == self.window.id() => match event {
                WindowEvent::CloseRequested => control_flow.exit(),
                WindowEvent::Resized(physical_size) => {
                    log::info!("physical_size: {physical_size:?}");
                    surface_configured = false;
                    self.resize(*physical_size);
                }

                WindowEvent::RedrawRequested => {
                    self.window.request_redraw();

                    self.system.update();
                }

                _ => {}
            },
            _ => {}
        })
        .unwrap();
}


OP states they "cant use a function that needs &mut self" I don't see how changing run to run(&mut self, EventLoop<()>) helps given these constraints.

@cafce25 "I try to call my functions I created earlier but somehow I cant use a function that needs &mut self" - I read that as a description of the error (on calling resize), and not a constraint on run. I'll remove if OP confirms otherwise though.

Doh! That is another way to read this. I guess OP has to clarify.
